# Converted 0.4 from base 10 to base 2, but the result isn't correct even though the procedure is right

Tags: binary, base-conversion

I am trying to convert 0.4 from base 10 to base 2.
This is what I did:

```
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 
0.8 * 2 = 1.6
0.6 * 2 = 1.2
0.2 * 2 = 0.4
0.4 * 2 = 0.8
0.8 * 2 = 1.6
```

Because 0.8 and 1.6 are repeated, I stop right here, and "0110" is what I got. But, 0.0110 is 0.375 in base 2, not 0.4.
So obviously, I did something wrong, can anyone point out where the error is?

Comment: Hint: is 1/3 equal to 0.3?

Comment: no, it is 0.33333333............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/frac.htm) they say, that once it's started to repeat itself, it means, that it's just a [recurring fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal). So I believe, 0.4<sub>10</sub> = 0.(0110)<sub>2</sub> meaning that `0110` -part is recurring, it goes 0.011001100110...

Comment: So, 0.4 is not recurring on base 10, but is recurring on base 2? When you say recurring, do you mean the same thing as "1/3" in decimal form, which is 0.3333333....

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, fraction can be recurring in one base and not-recurrent in another